# accelerometerSt.exe isn't compatible with latest windows 10 update

Tags: windows, accelerometer

AccelerometerSt.exe isn't compatible with latest update and tells me that uninstalling then reinstalling may help.

HP Pavilion laptop.

HP 3D DriveGuard only compatible with Windows 8 and below.

What should I do? 
Uninstall? 
Download another Accelerometer?
Thanks!

Comment: This is the Error Msg appearing when I turned on my laptop AccelerometerSt.exe- System Error
The code execution cannot proceed because VCRUNTIME 140.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on Microsoft Community. Sorry I lost the link:
Uninstall Visual C++ Redistributable and HP 3D DriveGuard. Then install latest version Visual C++ Redistributable. Restart your PC. Then install HP DriverGuard appropriate for your model computer and latest version. It worked for me. I am just sorry I cannot find the correct link to thank them.

Comment: Here's a link: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/AccelerometerSt-exe-System-Error-VCRUNTIME140-dll/td-p/6137960

Answer (score 0):

I had Windows 10 update compatibility issues with 3D DriveGuard which were fixed with the latest driver (version 6.0.45.1) from here: https://support.hp.com/au-en/document/c05841987

Generally speaking you should try the latest driver from HP via this page: https://support.hp.com/au-en/drivers

Answer (score -1):

What kind of drives do you have and do you carry your laptop around?  If you have SSDs exclusively, or you never move your laptop, then you do not need to "park the drive heads," which is what HP 3D DriveGuard is supposed to do in case of impact.  In that case you can just uninstall HP 3D Driveguard, and the error messages will stop.