# AcclerometerSt.exe - System Error, VCRUNTIME140.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: windows-10, drivers, accelerometer

I recently purchased a refurbished HP ENVY m6 notebook (running 64-bit Windows 10)  and upon startup, the error message (written in the title of this question) appears.  After researching the problem, my initial plan was to uninstall HP 3D Driveguard, restart the notebook, and then install the hardware version located at the following link, which from what I can figure out is the one compatible with my system: http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp78001-78500/sp78033.exe

I originally posted this question because I had come across a similar question on this site that also recommended updating Visual C++ Redistributable, but did not go into detail as to why this additional step is needed (link here: [accelerometerSt.exe isn't compatible with latest windows 10 update](https://superuser.com/questions/1211142/accelerometerst-exe-isnt-compatible-with-latest-windows-10-update)). I know very little about troubleshooting problems and working with drivers on Windows, so I was hoping someone could help clarify how these were connected and if I did in fact need to update this driver as well.

The latest update for Visual C++ Redistributable that is currently on this notebook is from 2013, and I've been told that I will need the 2015 update for the HP 3D Driveguard update version that I listed to work properly.  So if I follow the installation instructions for the vc_redist.x64.exe file (located here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True&e6b34bbe-475b-1abd-2c51-b5034bcdd6d2=True&fa43d42b-25b5-4a42-fe9b-1634f450f5ee=True), and then follow the steps I outlined in the first paragraph of this question, should this fix the problem that is causing the error message that I keep getting at startup?

Comment: So do you have the required version of the Visual C++ Redistributable (2015) installed, because, your question isn't clear if that's the case.  You should edit your question and clarify this point

Comment: Sry, I tried to indicate that I'm completely out of my depth when it comes to troubleshooting on Windows, that's why I asked for comments to let me know if I was leaving out relevant info that would be needed to answer (thanks!). Latest version I see is 2013, so do I need 2015?  I had seen this driver referenced on the other link but had no idea how it related, so I was seeking clarification on that point.  I'm new to this site and don't want to be a nuisance or post incorrectly, so do I need to go back and edit the original question to reflect this info?  Thanks for your help and patience..

Comment: Yes; You need 2015.  Update your question with the relevant information.  2013 would provide and entirely different version of that file which the program cannot use.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone experiences a similar problem in the future, this is how I was able to fix the problem and remove the AccelerometerSt.exe error message:

1) Installed the 2015 update for Visual C++ Redistributable 2) Uninstalled HP 3D Driveguard  3) Restarted the computer 4) Installed the updated HP 3D Driveguard from the link in my original question